# How can I recover a corrupted, partially pickled file?

Tags: python, pickle, corruption, dill

My program was killed while serializing data (a `dict`) to disk with `dill`. I cannot open the partially-written file now.

Is it possible to partially or fully recover the data? If so, how?

Here's what I've tried:

```
>>> dill.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "lib/python3.4/site-packages/dill/dill.py", line 288, in load
    obj = pik.load()
EOFError: Ran out of input
>>>
```

The file is not empty:

```
>>> os.stat(filename).st_size
31110059
```

Note: all data in the dictionary was comprised of python built-in types.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The pure-Python version of `pickle.Unpickler` keeps a stack around even if it encounters an error, so you can probably get at least something out of it:

```
import io
import pickle

# Use the pure-Python version, we can't see the internal state of the C version
pickle.Unpickler = pickle._Unpickler

import dill

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = [1, 2, {3: 4, "5": ('6',)}]
    data = dill.dumps(obj)

    handle = io.BytesIO(data[:-5])  # cut it off

    unpickler = dill.Unpickler(handle)

    try:
        unpickler.load()
    except EOFError:
        pass

    print(unpickler.stack)
```

I get the following output:

```
[3, 4, '5', ('6',)]
```

The pickle data format isn't that complicated. Read through the Python module's source code and you can probably find a way to hook all of the `load_` methods to give you more information.

Comment: I'm the `dill` author.  Indeed, pickling is just dumping to a string, so you should be able to recover up to the last object dumped when it failed.  `pickle` and thus `dill` pickles recursively, so be warned that the "last object" means "the last object that was the target of a `dump`".

Comment: With the newest version of dill it failed with: 
AttributeError: 'Unpickler' object has no attribute 'stack'. 
How can this be achieved in new dill versions? which version did you use?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on the above answer, but to extend Blender's answer:

unpickler.metastack worked for me, dill v0.3.5.1 (though you could do it without dill, afaik). stack did exist, but was an empty list.

Also, with dill I got a UnpicklingError rather than EOFError. This could also be partly because of how my file got corrupted (ran out of disk space)

Comment: Thanks for the tip about metastack. I wrote some example code (without dill) https://stackoverflow.com/a/76686521/360265