# Recover data from a corrupted pkl file

Tags: python, data-recovery

A pkl I am working on got corrupted from full disk issues

Is there a way to recover some of the data that was in it?

The onlly solution i have found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49222838/how-can-i-recover-a-corrupted-partially-pickled-file). The issue is that currently with the newest version of dill it failed with: AttributeError: 'Unpickler' object has no attribute 'stack'.

Comment: Did you try with older Pickle and dill versions?